# If many users run "git push" at the same time, are those commands ran sequentially or concurrently on the server?

Tags: git, githooks

I have a scenario in which I need to create, add and commit a file to the repo for every .hbs file that is added or changes. I do all that in a `post-receive` hook because the requirements state that it must be done server-side.

In order to do that, I keep a working copy of the repo on the server (Gitlab) so I can add the file to the repo. In my hook, I generate the file then do `git add`, `git commit` and `git push`.

What worries me with that approach is what happens if many people push at the same time? If the push operations run concurrently, I think it might be problematic. But if they are run sequentially, then I see no problem.

So my question is: Can I assume that `git push` (particularly the `post-receive` hook) run sequentially on the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no: you cannot make this assumption.  You can make some others, though.

Any Git repository will *lock* any given reference while updating it.  This is true even on a purely-local Git operation, without any client/server stuff going on: if you run one `git commit` in one window, and another `git commit` in another window, at the same time, on the same branch, only one at a time can actually update that branch name.

That said, the actual *updating* occurs *before* the post-receive hook runs.  All locks (on branch names, and on the index itself) are released after the `pre-receive` and `update` hooks run, before the `post-update` hook runs.  So we can construct some race scenarios like this:

- Alice runs `git push` (from Alice's computer) to send commit `a123456` to the server and to ask the server to set the server's `master` branch to identify commit `a123456`.
- Bob runs `git push` (from Bob's computer) to send commit `b789abc` to the server and to ask the server to set the server's `feature` to identify commit `b789abc`.
- Carol runs `git push` to send commit `fedcba9` to the server and to ask the server to set the server's `master` to identify commit `fedcba9`.

One of these three will "win the race" to start updating.  Let's assume, without (I hope) loss of generality, that it's Alice, and that Bob will go next and Carol will go third.  Alice's commit goes into the quarantine area,<sup>1</sup> and the server's pre-receive and update hooks get a chance to decide whether making the server's `master` identify `a123456` is a good idea.  If her `git push` is not forced, the server Git will first ensure that the *current* value of `master` is an ancestor of this proposed new commit, too—i.e., that the `git push` is a fast-forward operation.

If all goes well, Alice's commit is moved from quarantine to the main repository database and `master` now identifies `a123456` on the server.  The server releases all the locks and begins running the `post-receive` hook.  Since Bob is queued up, the server now (almost immediately—it's a separate process that has been waiting) takes Bob's commit `b789abc` and puts *that* in quarantine and starts the vetting process for the server's `refs/heads/feature`.  If all goes well, the commit moves from quarantine to the main database, `refs/heads/feature` now identifies `b789abc`, and Git spins off the post-receive hook.  (If the push is rejected, I *think* Git still spins off the post-receive hook, but now there are no updates in its stdin stream.  Let's assume the push is accepted.)

At this point Carol's push can run.  Her commit `fedcba9` almost certainly *does not* have `a123456` as an ancestor—the only way it *could* have it is if Carol got this from Alice earlier, after all—so after her commit goes into quarantine, her attempt to set `master` will be rejected unless she used `--force`.  The server Git then runs the post-receive hook, but with no updates in its stdin stream.  (Possibly, the post-receive hook doesn't run at all.)

If the first post-receive hook is still running, there are, at this point, *three* post-receive hooks running.  One has, in its stdin, an update to `refs/heads/master` from whatever hash ID it held before, to `a123456`.  One has, in its stdin, an update to `refs/heads/feature`, from whatever hash ID it held before, to `b789abc`.  The third has an empty stdin stream: there are no updates to perform.

What happens from here on out is, of course, up to you, the author of the post-receive hook.

---

<sup>1</sup>Quarantine areas were new in some post-2.0 Git version.  These details mostly don't matter; they're only really important if a pre-receive or update hook *rejects* some name-change.

Answer (score 0):

> Quarantine areas were new in some post-2.0 Git version. These details mostly don't matter; they're only really important if a pre-receive or update hook rejects some name-change.

The problem is: before Git 2.36, a failed push might not *clear* the quanrantine area, which could after other concurrent push.

With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), "`receive-pack`" checks if it will do any ref updates (various conditions could reject a push) before received objects are taken out of the temporary directory used for quarantine purposes, so that a push that is known-to-fail will *not leave crufts* that a future "`gc`" needs to clean up.

See [commit 5407764](https://github.com/git/git/commit/540776406974dfcacb77e94a42f4bdfd4b15b4fe) (29 Jan 2022) by [Chen Bojun (`cbj-bojun`)](https://github.com/cbj-bojun).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 867b520](https://github.com/git/git/commit/867b520301cc5e719b575edde7736ebe70a19298), 18 Feb 2022)</sup>

> ### [`receive-pack`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/540776406974dfcacb77e94a42f4bdfd4b15b4fe): purge temporary data if no command is ready to run
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Jiang Xin</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Teng Long</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Chen Bojun</sup>

> When pushing a hidden ref, e.g.:
>
> ```
> $ git push origin HEAD:refs/hidden/foo
> ```
>
> "`receive-pack`" will reject our request with an error message like this:
>
> ```
> ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/hidden/foo (deny updating a hidden ref)
> ```
>
> The remote side ("`git-receive-pack`") will not create the hidden ref as expected, but the pack file sent by "git-send-pack" is left inside the remote repository.
> I.e. the quarantine directory is not purged as it should be.
>
> Add a checkpoint before calling `"tmp_objdir_migrate()`" and after calling the "`pre-receive`" hook to purge that temporary data in the quarantine area when there is no command ready to run.
>
> The reason we do not add the checkpoint before the "`pre-receive`" hook, but after it, is that the "`pre-receive`" hook is called with a switch-off "`skip_broken`" flag, and all commands, even broken ones, should be fed by calling "`feed_receive_hook()`".